# Hibernate code generation for non identifying relation

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I have the following table structure,

```
TableA:
aid int, (PK)
name varchar(255),
bid
```

TableB is having composite primary key(bid, tid, mid)

```
TableB:
bid int, (PK)
tid int, (PK)
mid int, (PK)
name varchar(255)
```

When I try to generate code using the hibernate tools by adding it in eclipse I get error that "Foreign Key(TableA[TableB_TableBId]) must have same number of columns as referenced by primary key (TableB[bid,tid,mid]"

As this is a non identifying relationship I do not want to add the other columns(tid and mid) in TableA.

Is there a way to generate code for this kinda of scenario.

Am I missing any other configuration while generation?

Note: I am using eclipse juno(1.5.0.20120614-1633) and Hibernate Tools  "3.6.0.Final-v20130327-1513-B111"

**Update:**
Tried with latest eclipse Luna, there even connection is not getting created getting "Reading Schema error: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available" even though I have set the dialect

Answer (score 0):

I used Hibernate tool task to generate code for your tables and pojos are generated as expected.

```
Create Table Table1(
aid integer,
name varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (aid));

Create Table Table2(
bid integer,
tid integer, 
mid integer,
name varchar(255)
PRIMARY KEY (bid,tid,mid));

ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rel FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES Table1(aid);
```

And here is Pojos

```
public class Table1  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private int aid;
     private String name;
     private Set<Table2> table2s = new HashSet<Table2>(0);
     //getters and setters
}

public class Table2  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Table2Id id;
     private Table1 table1;
     private String name;
     //getters and setters
}

public class Table2Id  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private int bid;
     private int tid;
     private int mid;
     //getters and setters
}
```

You can use this [GitHub project](https://github.com/sunilpulugula/DataBaseToJava) to generate Pojos out of Database.Let me know if I miss anything from your question.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm m facing this problem with non identifying relationships, so for that, I need only one primary key (out of 3) from table2 to be referred in table1

Comment: with hibernate it is not possible to generate non identifying relation when a field is part of composite key. But I have a Work around , you have to prepare your hbm file without composite key and with only non identifying relation and generate pojo's out of hbms. This way you have non Identifying relation at pojo level and actual relations at DB layer.